# JNI Error even though Java is the latest version

Tags: java, exception

I've been trying to run a jar file with a class version 59.0, however it always gives me a JNI error saying I can only run class file versions up to 52.0

This is weird because I am on the latest version of Java and have restarted my computer.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MapConverter has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Please help!

Comment: How do you know you're running the latest version of Java? What does java -version say? Also, how do you run the jar file?

Comment: The version is "1.8.0_333". I am running the jar file from the command prompt as it requires you to set the image for it to use in the command prompt

Comment: I'm an idiot. I'm downloading from the wrong page. Sorry!

Comment: No worries, we all make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was downloading the "latest" version of java from the wrong page. I'm running Java 8.